# "tel:" disapears from href in link after site loads

Tags: javascript, html, joomla

for example in backend I insert this into content

```
<a href="tel:#####-#######" data-role="button" style="color: #6e6e6e;>05603-5019697</a>
```

and after saving and reloading site when i go inspect element "tel:" part of href is missing, and I don't know what can be the problem

Comment: Clear your browser cache ?

Comment: Can you see if this can be replicated in a JSFiddle? Assuming you're using the correct syntax this shouldn't be a problem. Try removing the - in the href, just incase.

Comment: found the problem it was "rns.matelso.de/webtracking.js" which it seems delete "tel:" prefix when used. I don't have any idea how to solve it

Comment: Hi, You missed the closing "  for style tag  style="color: #6e6e6e`"`;
I just tested on a standard joomla site and found no issue.  I have checked "rns.matelso.de/webtracking.js" file too. there is no code that should remove the tel.  whats your website url. where i can see the link.

Comment: I fixed it... there was extra bit of code that removed tel, because it was calling fallback_tn which had only number without tel: part. I simply added another var and attached it to this number, now it works. Thank you all for your help. It helped me to get to this idea